# Shopify: where would customization screens need to be added

Tags: shopify, shopify-api-node

I am in the planning phase for a shopify app that will add a tool on the checkout screens and I am a newbie to shopify.  I also need to provide admin. screens where the user can modify options that will change the tool to fit different scenarios.  On reading the docs., I am confused regarding what shopify options I need to use to pull this off.

1) For the part of the app that will display something on the checkout screens what would I need to do for providing this functionality?

2) For the admin. screens that make the tool appear on the checkout screens, what would I need to do for this to appear in the admin. section for shopify, embedded app, etc.?

It seems like I would need to split this into two separate apps.  Am I correct in this thinking?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add tools to checkout. You should do some research about Shopify Platform before scheming to make Apps. Once you understand the platform, you can dream up useful Apps. Asking questions about how and where to place admin screens reveals you have not really done any research, so expecting help here is likely not going to happen.

Comment: I have actually reviewed and am reviewing the docs. and tutorials around my current response, not to mention the current video I am watching which covers an article I read in their docs.  As I stated before, this is my first go at a shopify app so I am green regarding what I can achieve using the toolsets and am still learning the shopify nomeclature.  Can I add any visual components to the checkout screens, by tool that is what I meant?

Comment: If you have a Shopify Plus customer, you can alter checkout.liquid to suit their purposes. If not a Plus customer, then NO, you cannot alter checkout. End of story. You can add code to the cart, and the thank you page, but not checkout itself.